# Reversed map not same as map reversed

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, reverse

I am following the React tutorial (https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and found that a reversed map is not the same as a map reversed.

Change lines 87-96 of https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR (only lines 87 and 96 are changed in my snippets)

To see what I mean, click inside the tic tac toe board and look at the moves list. The first 2 code snippets give:

```
1. Go to game start
2. Go to move #1
3. Go to move #2
4. Go to move #3
...
```

but the last snippet gives (desired)

```
1. Go to move #3
2. Go to move #2
3. Go to move #1
4. Go to game start
...
```

Original (move list in ascending order)

```
const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
  const desc = move ?
    'Go to move #' + move :
    'Go to game start';
  return (
    <li key={move}>
      <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
    </li>
  );
});
```

Reverse then map (move list in ascending order)

```
const moves = history.slice(0).reverse().map((step, move) => {
  const desc = move ?
    'Go to move #' + move :
    'Go to game start';
  return (
    <li key={move}>
      <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
    </li>
  );
});
```

Map then reverse (move list in descending order)

```
const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
  const desc = move ?
    'Go to move #' + move :
    'Go to game start';
  return (
    <li key={move}>
      <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
    </li>
  );
}).slice(0).reverse();
```

Why do the last two code snippets give different results?

`history` is an array of game states:

```
let history = [
    {
        squares: [
            null, null, null,
            null, null, null,
            null, null, null,
        ],
    },
    {
        squares: [
            null, null, null,
            null, 'X', null,
            null, null, null,
        ],
    },
    {
        squares: [
            null, null, null,
            null, 'X', null,
            null, null, 'O',
        ],
    },
]
```

The example above shows 'X' player choosing center cell and then 'O' player choosing lower right cell.

Comment: Can you include a definition of `history`?

Comment: move is the `index` which is a number starting at 0, incremented for each iteration of the loop. When you reverse the array after iterating from 0 to 2, it will display as 2, 1, 0. If you reverse beforehand, the move/index will remain as usual, 0, 1, 2.

Comment: Sounds like George got it but when I was debugging, I found `history` to be referring to `window.history` which is not an array but a `History` that does not have `splice()` despite me defining it so you might want to be careful with that name.